# Visual Studio 2015 only allowing deletions in Typescript files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

For some reason, I can't append to my TypeScript files in VS2015 anymore. I can delete things, and undo those deletions, but I can't actually type anything in.

It started a bit after I installed the Markdown Mode extension, but disabling it didn't fix anything.

I am able to edit the transpiled JS files, which is weird. It appears to be just .ts files.

Edit: I believe it has something to do with this:

```
<record>596</record>
<time>2016/05/31 17:52:41.977</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
<description>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.WebLinter.LinterUtilities.IsFileSupported(String fileName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.ErrorTagger.LintErrorTaggerProvider.CreateTagger[T](ITextBuffer textBuffer)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.GatherTaggers(ITextBuffer textBuffer)</description>
```

Comment: Most of these kinds of things follow the same basic flow: Start Visual Studio in Safe Mode, see if it's a problem. If not, start removing extensions/settings/etc.. Otherwise, reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: It works in Safe Mode, but reinstalling VS doesn't fix it.

Comment: Alright, it appears it's actually specific to this solution.

Comment: My last ditch fix VS for solution specific issues usually involve deleting the .SUO file in the solution and then restarting VS.

Comment: I'm having the same exact error as you. It still occurs in a brand new empty project, when trying to type in a newly added (empty) typescript file.

I've run VS in safe mode, tried repairing VS, removed the MEF component cache (from reading here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7204).

Comment: Also, still getting the error after uninstalling/reinstalling VS2015 w/Update 2. And after installing Update 3 RC.

Gist of the error (here)[https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2dde60cd41b6954f42857b15b8c435d4].

I am now able to edit typescript files after installing Update 3 RC, just get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try and look through your **solution config**, there is probably something in there that's preventing you from doing it. To prove that that's the case, create a new solution and see if everything works there fine. Sometimes the solution config will become corrupt and won't let you append to files in it directory.